# Confusion regarding state space?

Tags: state-space

I am trying to understand state space and I have came across a circuit as shown in attached snapshot. According to my understanding number of states will be equal to number of effective energy storage elements (after circuit simplification). So here in this snapshot circuit, number of states will be two, one state will be the voltage across C1 while the other state will be the voltage across C2? Please correct me if my understanding is wrong.

[image]

Comment: What about the currents flowing through Resistors R1 and R2?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are two independent energy storage elements, so there must be two states. The capacitor voltages, \$\large v_{\small C_1}\$ and \$\large v_{\small C_2}\$, are suitable states. Note that other choices are possible - any two states that completely define the system dynamics are acceptable.

Having selected the above states, you then need to obtain expressions for the state derivatives, \$\large\dot v_{\small C_1}\$  and \$\large\dot v_{\small C_2}\$, from the circuit  diagram, in order to build the A, B, and C matrices.

Comment: What about the currents flowing through Resistors R1 and R2? can they also be considered as states?

Comment: @engr, in that case it has to be possible to express \$\dot{I}_1\$ and \$\dot{I}_2\$ as functions of \$ I_1\$ and \$I_2\$, and the circuit parameters. This may be difficult. It can also be done with the charges on C1 and C2.